# Initializing an instance of struct and getting unresolved identifier error

Tags: ios, uitableview, struct, initialization

I want to initialize an instance of a struct called TaskList in my TableViewController, but I'm getting a "Use of unresolved identifier 'tasks'" error every place I used 'tasks'. It worked fine when I was declaring the var tasks within the class, but now that it's an initialization of a var declared in another .swift file, I'm getting that error. I'm just learning Swift so I suspect this has something to do with the architecture or messing up how to call an object from another file. Does anyone know what I need to do to fix it? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks everybody!

Here's the UITableViewController code:

```
import UIKit

class LoLFirstTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    //var tasks:[Task] = taskData
    // Hashed out the above line (even though it worked) because replacing with
    // the below line because trying to get instance of TaskList containing all
    // properties instead of just the tasks as well as to allow multiple instances
    // of TaskList

    let exampleList = TaskList(buddy: exampleBuddy, phoneNumber: examplePhoneNumber, tasks: exampleTaskData)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 60.0
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tasks.count
    }

    @IBAction func cancelToLoLFirstTableViewController(_ segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
    }

    @IBAction func saveAddTask(_ segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
        if let AddTaskTableViewController = segue.source as? AddTaskTableViewController {

            if let task = AddTaskTableViewController.task {
                tasks.append(task)

                let indexPath = IndexPath(row: tasks.count-1, section: 0)
                tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
            }
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TaskCell", for: indexPath) as! TaskCell
        let task = tasks[indexPath.row]
            cell.task = task

        if cell.accessoryView == nil {
            let cb = CheckButton()
            cb.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped(_:forEvent:)), for: .touchUpInside)
            cell.accessoryView = cb
        }
        let cb = cell.accessoryView as! CheckButton
        cb.check(tasks[indexPath.row].completed)

        return cell
    }

    func buttonTapped(_ target:UIButton, forEvent event: UIEvent) {
        guard let touch = event.allTouches?.first else { return }
        let point = touch.location(in: self.tableView)
        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: point)

        var tappedItem = tasks[indexPath!.row] as Task
        tappedItem.completed = !tappedItem.completed
        tasks[indexPath!.row] = tappedItem

        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath!], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.none)
    }
}
```

And here's the code for the TaskList struct, if that helps:

```
import UIKit

struct TaskList {
    var buddy: String?
    var phoneNumber: String?
    var tasks: [Task]

    init(buddy: String?, phoneNumber: String?, tasks: [Task]) {
        self.buddy = buddy
        self.phoneNumber = phoneNumber
        self.tasks = tasks
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your struct the tasks array is not optional it means you have to pass an initialised tasks Array. Pass an initialised array or change your task array to optional as you have done with buddy and phoneNumber.

```
import UIKit

struct TaskList {
var buddy: String?
var phoneNumber: String?
// add a question mark to make your array of tasks optional
var tasks: [Task]?

init(buddy: String?, phoneNumber: String?, tasks: [Task]) {
    self.buddy = buddy
    self.phoneNumber = phoneNumber
    self.tasks = tasks
  }
}
```

Note: when you're using struct you can leave out the initialzer it will generate one automatically

```
import UIKit

struct TaskList {
   var buddy: String?
   var phoneNumber: String?
   var tasks: [Task]?
}
```

now in your viewController initialise the your example list

```
// as your tasks array is optional now even if you pass in a nil it will not crash but it will not have a tasks array
let exampleList = TaskList(buddy: exampleBuddy, phoneNumber: examplePhoneNumber, tasks: exampleTaskData)
```

remember to unwrap your array before using it otherwise your app can crash again if tasks array is nil. use if let or guard

```
if let tasks = exampleList.tasks {
   // now you can use your tasks array
}
```

Comment: If I unwrap the array in viewDidLoad the "Use of unresolved identifier 'tasks'" still remains in all of those places (because 'tasks' is only used under other functions besides viewDidLoad). If I unwrap it in cellForRowAt indexPath, the error remains for every use of 'tasks' in the other functions. Where should I be unwrapping it to effect all the functions or do I really need to unwrap it under each one? Thanks, Khalid, I appreciate the help! I'm a rookie at this.

Comment: The rule for optional is to always unwrap it first and then use it. Unless your 1000% sure then you can force unwrap it. Otherwise you have to use the if let in every method that you want to access it. Also you have to make sure that you're passing some data in the tasks are

Comment: Passing some data in the tasks are? What do you mean by that?